# internet explorer_hidden general purpose

Tags: internet-explorer, hidden

surprised to see two instances of "internet explorer_hidden" from my windows inspector. I have no clue what it is for. Can anybody please shine some light on the use of this? Thanks!

im running a win7 on x64 machine. I was using SWAPY to inspect some windows dialogs that im working on thats when i saw the instance of the hidden explorer.

Comment: Can you please try to provide detailed information about the issue? Like Which OS you are using? How you got that? Inform us if there are any steps to reproduce the issue. It can be possible that it is used for any internal operation of IE. If you want to remove it than you can try to use a third party app called Vista switcher which has an option to remove it from the list. Ref: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/34062/how-to-fix-vistaswitcher-showing-blank-windows-in-the-list/ Let us know about the results.

Answer (score 0):

`Internet Explorer_Hidden` is the ClassName of a hidden IE window. `Internet Explorer_Server` is the ClassName when it is visible.

The ClassName of the window changes dynamically as you toggle the focus/visibility of the window.